# Construction of Non-σ-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Provide a set $ \Omega $ and a system of sets $ \mathcal{E} $ in $ \Omega $ such that the extension of $ \mathcal{E} $ by all countable unions of elements from $ \mathcal{E} $ and their complements does not form a $ \sigma $-algebra.

Actually, the task means the following: First, let $ E $ be extended by all countable unions of sets from $ E $. We call the resulting system $ E^{\prime} $. Then, we extend the system $ E^{\prime} $ by all complements of the sets from $ E^{\prime} $, and denote the resulting system as $ E^{\prime \prime} $. The aim of the task is to choose a system $ E $ in such a way that $ E^{\prime \prime} $ is not a $ \sigma $-algebra.

I tried several simple sets first, but they all ended up being a sigma-algebra. And my internet research didn't turn up anything that I could use either. Does anyone have an idea for such a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\Omega$ take some uncountable set and for $\mathcal E$ take the collection of infinitely countable sets.

Then $\mathcal E'=\mathcal E$ and $E\in\mathcal E''$ iff $E$ is infinitely countable or its complement is infinitely countable.

That means that e.g. the empty set is not an element of $\mathcal E''$.